# ng-repeat for object inside array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I am receiving an array of string arrays from my back-end. (Java - CXF-RS)

The size of an array in the string arrays vary from 1 to n. To read and populate it in my front-end, I am using ng-repeat.

Everything works fine except for one condition. If any of the string array has only one data in it, it is received as an Object. Hence ng-repeat is failing for those conditions.

Is there a work-around to fix this?

Comment: Change your backend so it only returns an array.

Comment: if you cant change your back-end then convert it into array just after response.

Comment: Yeah I am already doing that but I want to know if it is the proper way or if there is a better way.

Comment: If you could post some code or a jsbin demo we could post suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to force the server to return an Array every time. If that is not possible, you can check if the returned data is an array using:

  `angular.isArray()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray

and if it is not, then push the data onto the array that the ngRepeat is using.

Pseudo code:
1. Get data from server
2. In success callback initialize your array
3. If returned data is array, assign it to your array
4. if not, then push the data onto your array.

```
$http.get('url', function(data) {
  $scope.items = [];
  if(angular.isArray(data) {
     $scope.items = data; 
  } else {
    $scope.items.push(data);
  }
});
```

I havent checked this bit of code for syntax errors or linted it. This was just to give you an idea.